# Need Deeper Nesting in Android Menu

Tags: android, menu, nested

I have an Android Tide Application, which requires the user to select a tide station, and it has also several other menu items, totalling 6. My Enter Tide Station option is unweildly, fifty or more choices is too many. So I would like to break it down into submenus with various geographic areas listed, each would then have stations in that sub area listed. However, I have read that submenus cannot have further submenus, which prevents this.

**QUESTION:** What is the most standard way to accomplish this in Android?

**QUESTION:** Can I have a sub-application which is part of the APK, which is invoked from my menu, which would then have a full array of menu choices available, again; then I could pass back the result to my main application?

Comment: 1/ don't. that would puzzle you user. Use activities or Dialogs instead. 2/ yes.

Comment: Instead of a menu you can just create a Activity that handles this request and use startActivityForResult().

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I will build a separate activity which displays a map of the area with clickable station marks. This seems to be a standard android technique. Thanks again.